# Want to print original value in memory after changes

Tags: assembly, mips, memory-address

I have this code

```
    .globl main 

    .text

# The label 'main' represents the starting point
main:

    li    $v0,4        # print_string syscall code = 4
    la    $a0, theString    # load the address of msg
    syscall
    
    li    $v0,4        # print_string syscall code = 4
    la    $a0, newLine    # load the address of msg
    syscall
        
    jal capitalize    # call capitalize procedure

    # syscall to print value
    li      $v0, 4      
    move    $a0, $t2 
    syscall
    
    li    $v0,4        # print_string syscall code = 4
    la    $a0, newLine    # load the address of msg
    syscall
    
    li    $v0,4        # print_string syscall code = 4
    la    $a0, theString    # load the address of msg
    syscall

    li $v0, 10 # Sets $v0 to "10" to select exit syscall
    syscall # Exit

capitalize:

    li $t0,0
    la $t2,theString
    
    loopString:
        lb $t1, theString($t0)    # load the char
        beq $t1, 0, finishLoop    # If done with iteration of string finish loop
        bgt $t1, 'z', notLetter   # checks if char is not between 'a' and 'z'
        blt $t1, 'a', notLetter
        sub $t1, $t1, 32          # subtracts 32 from lowercase letter to get uppercase
        sb $t1, theString($t0)    # saves back the char

    notLetter: 
        # increments char loop by one
        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        j loopString
        
    finishLoop:    
    
        jr $ra

.data
theString: .asciiz "test"
newLine:   .asciiz "\n"
```

It currently prints

```
test
TEST
TEST
```

However, I am having trouble getting it to look like

```
test
test
TEST
```

Where the original string is printed twice. I was wondering if there are any tips I can get to fix this problem? I have thought about stack allocation, but after trying I kept on running into different problems.

Comment: The obvious way would be to print it *before* changing it, so you don't have to make a copy.  Otherwise instead of changing it in-place, yeah reserve some stack space and make your capitalize loop copy+change, storing into a different destination.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah that makes sense, how would you go about it. I've tested things like sw,sb,lw,lb with the stack and trying to reserve some space, however they all ended up giving me errors with errors regarding the address.

Comment: `addiu $sp, $sp, -32` would be the standard way to move the stack pointer down by 32 bytes to reserve space.  Look at how C compilers do it for a C function with local vars: https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score -1):

```
 .globl main 

    .text

# The label 'main' represents the starting point
main:

    li    $v0,4        # print_string syscall code = 4
    la    $a0, theString    # load the address of msg
    syscall
    
    li    $v0,4        # print_string syscall code = 4
    la    $a0, newLine    # load the address of msg
    syscall
        
    jal capitalize    # call capitalize procedure

    # syscall to print value
    li      $v0, 4      
    la    $a0, oldString 
    syscall
    
    li    $v0,4        # print_string syscall code = 4
    la    $a0, newLine    # load the address of msg
    syscall
    
    li    $v0,4        # print_string syscall code = 4
    la    $a0, theString    # load the address of msg
    syscall

    li $v0, 10 # Sets $v0 to "10" to select exit syscall
    syscall # Exit

capitalize:

    li $t0,0
    la $t2,theString
    
    loopString:
        lb $t1, theString($t0)    # load the char
        beq $t1, 0, finishLoop    # If done with iteration of string finish loop
        bgt $t1, 'z', notLetter   # checks if char is not between 'a' and 'z'
        blt $t1, 'a', notLetter
        sub $t1, $t1, 32          # subtracts 32 from lowercase letter to get uppercase
        sb $t1, theString($t0)    # saves back the char

    notLetter: 
        # increments char loop by one
        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        j loopString
        
    finishLoop:    
    
        jr $ra

.data

oldString: .asciiz "test"
theString: .asciiz "test"
newLine:   .asciiz "\n"
```

Comment: Manually hard-coding a 2nd copy of the same data isn't a very useful answer in general.  I wouldn't recommend that future readers do it this way.  Also, a Stack Overflow answer should explain what the change was, not bury it in a huge code block with no explanation.